# Read in a file with straight html

Tags: html

In an enviroment where I can't use scripting language, and must use straight html, and I need to render the contents of a file in a webpage.  Is there a way to do this?  Or is a scripiting language required.

Comment: Are you doing this statically (i.e. you can make a web page with the content of the file and publish it) or do you need to incorporate the file at the time of the web request? How often does the file change (e.g. can you write the page every few minutes using a server-side script?)? What format is the file content?

Answer (score 3):

```
<object type="text/plain" data="path/to/plain/text/file.txt">
    <p>Your browser must support the OBJECT element.</p>
</object>
```

That is the only effective way I can think of. IFRAMES/FRAMES work too, in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 1):

If you just can't do PHP or anything similar, you could also try SSI, which I think is pretty standard:
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/article.php/3473341

Just curious; why can't you use a scripting language?  Does the file reside on a local fileshare instead of a web server?

Even if you can't do any server-side scripting, you could probably use some JavaScript/AJAX to read the file and render it nicely:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxincludes.htm

Otherwise, the iframe suggestions others have posted should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've done straight HTML, but couldn't you use an `<iframe>` or `<object>` tag and point the `src=` attribute to the text file in question? Or is special rendering needed for the file?

Answer (score 0):

No, HTML can't do any dynamic scripting..

Answer (score 0):

If the file just changes from time to time and its content format is appropriate you could re-write the web page using a server-side script at an appropriate interval and it can then  be read by clients using standard HTML.

The server-side script need not be part of, or even known to the web server software (for example it could be a bash script or a standalone program run via a cron job).

Answer (score 0):

Probably not very helpful but if your data is in XML file, you could always try XSLT?